# Returning a value after callback in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I return a value after a callback in kotlin, I tried using Thread.sleep but it doesn't work

```
   fun searchColorFromAPI(): Colors {
    val service: RetrofitService = ServiceGenerator.createService(RetrofitService::class.java)
    val result: MutableList<String> = arrayListOf()
    val call: Call<Colors?>? = service.unityConverter(result)
    call?.enqueue(object : Callback<Colors?> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Colors?>?, response: Response<Colors?>) {
            //switchProgressVisibility()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val serviceResponse: Colors? = response.body()

                if (serviceResponse != null) {
                    mColors = serviceResponse

                }
                else {
                    //buildToast(getString(R.string.null_response))
                }
            }

            else {
                //buildToast(getString(R.string.response_unsuccessful))
                val errorBody: ResponseBody = response.errorBody()
                Log.e(TAG, errorBody.toString())
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Colors?>?, t: Throwable?) {
           /* buildToast(getString(R.string.error_calling_service))
            Log.e(TAG, t?.message)*/
        }
    })

    return mColors
}
```

Always, the mColors is returned before the onFailure or onResponse because they're asynchronous. Before this code was in MainActivity but I was advised to take off, but now when I try get mColors I get the empty value before and after the onResponse is executed, please I'm still learning Kotlin and Android.

Comment: Kotlin's lambda function is useful for the callback. Check this answer for a callback from function. [ https://stackoverflow.com/a/59942825/12688463 ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that `Retrofit` `call` is `asynchronous`, so as soon as you call `searchColorFromAPI` it returns you `mColors` but the `API` call may not have been made yet, so you get the mColors value before API call.

To solve this issue, you can do

1. Use `callback`, ***this will require little modification in your current setup, but the 2nd option is preferable over this.*** Using `callback` your function should look like this.

   ```
   /* Now instead of returning a value, your function takes a function (named callback) 
      as parameter. when your api call finishes, you can call the callback function and 
      pass the api response.
    */
   fun searchColorFromAPI(callback: (Colors?) -> Unit) {
       val service: RetrofitService = ServiceGenerator.createService(RetrofitService::class.java)
       val result: MutableList<String> = arrayListOf()
       val call: Call<Colors?>? = service.unityConverter(result)
       call?.enqueue(object : Callback<Colors?> {
           override fun onResponse(call: Call<Colors?>?, response: Response<Colors?>) {
               //switchProgressVisibility()
               if (response.isSuccessful) {
                   val serviceResponse: Colors? = response.body()
                   /** pass API response to callback */
                   callback(serviceResponse)
               }
               else {
                   val errorBody: ResponseBody = response.errorBody()
                   Log.e(TAG, errorBody.toString())
                   callback(null)
               }
           }

           override fun onFailure(call: Call<Colors?>?, t: Throwable?) {
               callback(null)
           }
       })
   }
   ```

And in your `activity` declare a `function` as follows.

```
// This function will be called when your api call finishes
// and it will give you the api response
fun apiCallback(colors: Colors?){
      if(colors == null){
        // API Call failed
    }
    else{
        // use colors as returned by API
    }
}
```

And now call to `searchColorFromApi` should look like this

```
searchColorFromApi(apiCallback)
```

2. Use [Live Data](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData), declare following `field` in your `viewmodel`, if you are not using `viewmodel` then declare it in the `class` which has `searchColorFromApi` function.

   ```
   var colors: MutableLiveData<Colors> = MutableLiveData()
   ```

and modify your `searchColorFromAPI` function as follows

```
fun searchColorFromAPI() {
        val service: RetrofitService = ServiceGenerator.createService(RetrofitService::class.java)
        val result: MutableList<String> = arrayListOf()
        val call: Call<Colors?>? = service.unityConverter(result)
        call?.enqueue(object : Callback<Colors?> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Colors?>?, response: Response<Colors?>) {
                //switchProgressVisibility()
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val serviceResponse: Colors? = response.body()
                    if (serviceResponse != null) {
                       colors.postValue(response.body)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    colors.postValue(null)
                    val errorBody: ResponseBody = response.errorBody()
                    Log.e(TAG, errorBody.toString())
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Colors?>?, t: Throwable?) {
                colors.postValue(null)
            }
        })
    }
```

and in your `activity` do following

```
  fun setupObservers(){
       yourApiCallingClass.colors.observe(this, Observer {
        // this code is called when ever value of color field changes
       })
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You can use live data ,that gets updated once the callback receives ,the same live data is observed by the caller fragment/activity
2. You can use coroutines to return a value from function which has asyn calls in it.
3. You can use interface callbacks to activity/ fragment to trigger the updates received from retrofit calls.

Comment: i agree with your answer, but you haven't actually shown OP how to do any of these, so i don't think it adds much value :) you should consider adding simple examples to each of these